# Printing product of numbers from Nested Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, key

```
db = {'A':{(1,2): 3, (4,5): 6, (7,8): 9}, 'B': {(9,8):7, (6,5): 4, (3,2): 1 }}
```

I have a dictionary db, and I'm trying to print the values, but my code doesn't work. I know it has something to do with the i.keys in the print function, but how to I make it print the correct product.

```
for i in db.values():
    for x in i.keys():
        if x[1] >= 1:
            print(x[1]*i.values)
```

it should print:

```
6
30
72
56
20
2
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @RicardoAbe sorry! I edited it to show what the results should print

Answer (score 1):

Below solution will print the list containing the product of two numbers(tuple) inside the list and I hope there will be only two numbers inside each tuple.

`List comprehension` simplifies the code and reduces the number of lines of code.

```
value = [  x[0].__mul__(x[1]) for i in db.values() for x in i.keys() ]
```

Output

```
[2, 20, 56, 72, 30, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

At line 4, the variable `i` is a dictionary, so when you execute `x[1]*i.values`, you are multiplying an integer (`x[1]`) by the built-in method `values` from `dict`. Even if you put the parenthesis, `i.values()` will return a collection of values from your current second-level dictionary. Therefore, you need to use the key `x`, so that `i[x]` will return an integer:

```py
for i in db.values():
    for x in i.keys():
        if x[1] >= 1:
            print(x[1]*i[x])
```

Another way to solve your problem:

```py
for i in db.values():
    for (_, j), value in i.items():
        if j >= 1:
            print(j*value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `reversed` function to generate the dict values and the keys of the sub-dicts in reverse order:

```
for d in reversed(db.values()):
    for a, b in reversed(d):
        print(a * b)
```

This outputs:

```
6
30
72
56
20
2
```